# What is the song used in Akame ga Kill during the Budou vs Mine fight?

Tags: music, akame-ga-kill

In Akame ga Kill, there is a guitar song played in ep 21 Budou vs Mine and I can't seem to find it or any info about it. Does anyone know anything?

Comment: It's probably on the second OST, which comes out in three days: http://vgmdb.net/album/49691.

Answer (score 1):

It called "Adramelech" just like Budou's Imperial Arm.

Comment: Please extend your answer with a bit more information. You could for example refer to album on VGMDB as mentioned in [senshin's comment](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20079/what-is-the-song-used-in-akame-ga-kill-during-the-budou-vs-mine-fight#comment26983_20079)